# I made a money system but then when the money gets taken away it syncs for every client

Tags: lua, roblox

So this is the code by the way the script Is a normal script not a local one

```
    if Money.Value > Price then
        
        print("Called")
        
        Money.Value -= Price
        
        -- WGlowStick is inside of Replicated storage
        
        WGlowStick:Clone().Parent = Plr:WaitForChild("Backpack")

        WGlowStick:Clone().Parent = Plr.StarterGear 
        
    end
    
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

A "normal" script is called a server script.
You have to understand how the server scripts work.
It runs on the server, for every player in the game so you can't get the local player using server script. Client and server are separated.

So, to make a money system you have to save money value for each player on the server like so:

```
local Players = game:GetService('Players')

local Money = {}
local Prices = {
  Item1 = 100,
  Item2 = 200,
  Item3 = 1000
}

local function buy(player, item)  -- use remote event to call it from the client
  if (Money[player.UserId] and Money[player.UserId] >= Prices[item]) then
    Money[player.UserId] = Money[player.UserId] - Prices[item]
    -- give item
  end
end

-- When any player joins, set their money to 0
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(
  function(player)
    Money[player.UserId] = 0
  end
)

-- When any player leaves, set their money to nil
Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(
  function(player)
    Money[player.UserId] = nil
  end
)
```